# How to push working tree files to remote location on commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Ok so I am a complete git noob but understand the basics. So lets say that I have a GIT repo at bitbucket. Is it possible to push the working tree from bitbucket to my dev site (dev.example.com) when I push changes to my bitbucket repo?

Comment: I am sorry ... It is bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

BitBucket has a POST service capability which you can leverage to do what you want: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+bitbucket+POST+Service

Comment: Using this would I just create a php file that when posted to it uses the location of the working tree to download the latests files to the server?

I am working with php and only want the working files